# how to implement multiple request values for single field in django

Tags: python, django, curl

With this curl command I am requesting for only "Books" for field "ProductName"

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/Productfilter/ -d '{"ProductName":"Books"}' -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

Api code:

```
 def Productfilter(self, request, format=None)
   queryset = Model.objects.filter(ProductName=request['ProductName'])
   ser = ModelSerializer(queryset, many=True)
      for item in ser.data:
         sendData.append({"ProductUrl": item['ProductUrl']}]   
   return sendData
```

I want to implement for multiple request values for same field.
Like I want something like this--->

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/Productfilter/ -d '{"ProductName":"Books","Pencil","Copy"}' -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

Please suggest the curl command for this type of requests and what modification to be done in coding of `def Productfilter`.

views.py

```
class Productfilter(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):

        request.data['PubIp'] = getUserIP(request)
        returnData = ApiFiltReq.Productfilter(self, request.data, format=None)
        if returnData == "RECORD_NOT_FOUND":  # bad request
            return Response(ErrorCodes.ERROR_CODE_LIST[returnData], status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        elif returnData == "DJANGO_ENTRY_FAILED":
            return Response(ErrorCodes.ERROR_CODE_LIST[returnData], status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response(returnData, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, if you're only asking for data you should use a GET request.

Second thing, I assume that this `ProductName=request['ProductName']` is a typo and you're really using `request.POST[xxx]` (which should be `request.GET[xxx]` actually cf first point above)

wrt/ how you can get multiple values for the same key on the Django side, you just have to use `request.GET.getlist(xxx)` and change your query to `Model.objects.filter(ProductName__in=yyy)`:

```
def Productfilter(self, request, format=None)
    names = request.GET.getlist('ProductName')
    queryset = Model.objects.filter(ProductName__in=names)
    # etc
```

for the cURL part you'll have to check the FineManual but IIRC this should work:

```
curl -G http://localhost:8000/Productfilter/ --d ProductName=Books -d ProductName=Pencil -d ProductName=Copy
```

or just pass a plain querystring in your url:

```
curl -G http://localhost:8000/Productfilter/?ProductName=Books&ProductName=Pencil&ProductName=Copy
```

Comment: I understood what you said...I tried to do.. Its giving 'dict' object has no attribute 'GET'

Comment: Then you didn't post enough code (specially what class your `ProductFilter` belongs to and what exactly he gets passed as "request"). I of course assumed a Django HTTPRequest instance, it seems it's a `dict`... which might be a problem since a `dict` doesn't have a `getlist` method either.

Comment: I don't see how the code you added relates to what you already posted, but you're obviously using at least a couple 3rd part apps. I guess you will first have to browse those apps docs and source code to find out what really gets passed to  your function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def Productfilter(self, request, format=None)
   queryset = Model.objects.filter(ProductName=request.data['ProductName'], Pencil=request.data['Pencil'])
   ser = ModelSerializer(queryset, many=True)
      for item in ser.data:
         sendData.append({"ProductUrl": item['ProductUrl']}]   
   return sendData
```

and the curl command will look like this:

```
curl -X POST \
http://localhost:8000/Productfilter/ \
-d ProductName=Books
-d Pencil=Copy
-H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

Hope it helps!